# adding a colon after every two letters in an alphanumeric string in shell

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

So i have an alphanumeric string 10006cc2190ab011 i am trying to add a colon after every two letters in this alphanumeric string.

```
this is the string : 10006cc2190ab011 
i want it be - 10:00:6c:c2:19:0a:b0:11
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `sed` solution:

```
$ echo 10006cc2190ab011 | sed 's/../&:/g; s/:$//'
10:00:6c:c2:19:0a:b0:11
```

Replaces each non-overlapping pair of characters with the same pair plus `:`. In the end removes the trailing `:` (if input text had even length).

Comment: Thanks! exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
str=10006cc2190ab011; str="${str//??/${.sh.match}:}"; echo ${str%:}
```

is doing the same replacement without the use of an external command, just using ksh-internals.

Doing the same as in `sed` (the other answer). Replace in $str every `//` two charactes `??` with `/` the matched string and a `:` (every match is kept in the ksh-variable `${.sh.match}`). Then print $str without the last `%` ':'.

Comment: Can you explain?